# Maximum Network throughput for SWIFT storage

Tags: networking, performance-tuning, openstack

I have a SWIFT cluster deployed as part of Openstack which is currently giving me a max throughput of 95 MBS(Megabytes per second). There are 6 proxy servers and 6 storage nodes with replication factor of 3. Network Connectivity for backend storage nodes is via 10G network.

The storage nodes are all using 22x1 TB HDD drives.

While accessing large objects such as video on SWIFT cluster, the max throughput is around ~95 Mbps as mentioned.

Some applications are now demanding a higher throughput of 95 GBps(Gigabytes per second).

What will it take to reach this level of throughput (From object store to Virtual machine in openstack). Do I need to have everything in SSD storage, increase number of proxy servers or have the frontend proxy servers also use 10G network?

Comment: MBS or Mbps? which is it?

Comment: It is MB/s.  swift download f Test 
[headers 0.399s, total 8.890s, 95.287 MB/s

Comment: 95.287MB/s * 8bits/byte = 762.296 Mbps. Not quite 1Gbps, but not far. How do you plan on getting 95GBps * 8bits/byte = 760 Gbps out of a 10Gbps network?

Comment: I do not have an answer. Hence the question!